# Regular Expression - Match all between BEGIN and END

Tags: regex, string, filter, expression

I'm trying to find out how to make a regular expression to match all text between the first "BEGIN" and the last "END" of a procedure block.

Here's the text which I want to filter:

```
PROCEDURE MyFirstFunction()@12345
VAR
    TESTVAR@1 : Record 1;
    TESTVAR@2 : Record 2;
BEGIN
    // Here begins the code
    IF 1 = 1 THEN BEGIN
        IF 2 <> 1 THEN BEGIN
            MESSAGE('2 is not equal to 1');
        END;
        MESSAGE('1 is equal to 1');
    END;
END;

PROCEDURE MySecondFunction()@123456
VAR
    TESTVAR@1 : Record 1;
    TESTVAR@2 : Record 2;
BEGIN
    // Here begins the code
    IF 1 = 1 THEN BEGIN
        IF 2 <> 1 THEN BEGIN
            MESSAGE('2 is not equal to 1');
        END;
        MESSAGE('1 is equal to 1');
    END;
END;

PROCEDURE MyThirdFunction()@123457
VAR
    TESTVAR@1 : Record 1;
    TESTVAR@2 : Record 2;
BEGIN
    // Here begins the code
    IF 1 = 1 THEN BEGIN
        IF 2 <> 1 THEN BEGIN
            MESSAGE('2 is not equal to 1');
        END;
        MESSAGE('1 is equal to 1');
    END;
END;
```

I already tried it with a recursive regular expression, but this didn't work.

Here's the regular expression I worked on:

```
BEGIN(((?!BEGIN|END;).)|(?R))*END;
```

But I only get the second beginning of the first function.

Here's the link to regex101.com to test the regular expression:
https://regex101.com/r/ZoBm6h/1

Comment: Pobably, you may just use [`(?sm)^BEGIN$.*?^END;$`](https://regex101.com/r/fAZLRm/2). Or, [`(?sm)^BEGIN$(((?!^(?:BEGIN|END;)$).)|(?R))*^END;$`](https://regex101.com/r/fAZLRm/1)

Comment: Regex is not the tool for lexical analysis. Use ANTLR or something similar...

Comment: Hello Wiktor and Andrew. To Wiktor: Thank you, but when it comes to complex code blocks like in this case: https://regex101.com/r/t6bEcT/1 the patterns doesn't work anymore. To Andrew: I'm gonna look ANTLR up, thank you for your answers!

Comment: @Kevin I think my answer might still be salvageable with your data.  Check the updated demo link under my last comment.

Comment: @Kevin with `sed` command which is using 2 buffers and regular expression and for which a script could be provided, you will be able to do what you are looking for, see http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html
This remark works also for `awk` http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html

Answer (score -1):

I think the logic you want for the negative lookahead is that it should greedily consume everything after `BEGIN` until hitting the last `END`, provided that it also does not see the text `PROCEDURE`, which would mean that it's gone too far and has entered into the next procedure block.

```
BEGIN((?!PROCEDURE).)*END;
```

### Demo

Comment: Hello Tim. This pattern doesn't work when it comes to complex code blocks like in this case: https://regex101.com/r/t6bEcT/1 ..

Comment: @Kevin Yes, [it does work](https://regex101.com/r/t6bEcT/2).  You need to turn on DOT ALL mode for newline.  As the comments said, you really should use a formal parser if you can't get a fairly simple regex to do what you want.  Regex doesn't cope so well with nested content, which is exactly what code is.

Comment: Thank you. Yes I saw it! :) This is perfect. I have a last question if you don't mind: how can I get the name of the procedures (like PROCEDURE TestMethod@1234 and the variable block below) and the declared variables also with the regular expression - I'll try it for myself but when you have some kind of advice or solution, please let me now. :-)

Comment: You should update your question with the language you are using.  Adding capture groups won't do very much running in a regex demo tool.

Comment: The language is called C/AL - it's very uncommon. :-)

Comment: You may want to open a new question.  What you're asking for is at least one more completely separate regex.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to match all blocks, you can also use this Regex :

`BEGIN((?!^(?!PROCEDURE)$).)*END`

Comment: Your answer is basically a copy of mine.  And, most importantly, [your answer doesn't work](https://regex101.com/r/t6bEcT/3).